# Printing to wireless printer disconnects netbook from router

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lexmark-printer

I have a netbook loaded with Windows 7: Home Premium. I also have a x4550 Lexmark wireless printer. Whenever I try to print from my netbook, the printer starts printing and then abruptly stops. Then the Wi-Fi status icon on the printer then starts flashing orange (meaning there's connection problems with the router).

Another peculiarity is that my netbook gets disconnected from the wireless router when printing. I'm only able to print one page before it disconnects the netbook from the router.

I am able to print from any other PC except the one loaded with Windows 7. The drivers on the netbook are up to date for the printer as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: and which netbook, if i may ask?

Comment: @Molly Toshiba Mini NB205

Comment: Is it causing other computers/devices to drop the association to the router as well? Try updating the wireless card drivers on the laptop. Try plugging your netbook into the router with an ethernet cable, turn off the wireless radio, and see if that works without dropping the printer's association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was.

My router is configured for DHCP with IP addresses starting at **192.168.1.100**. I went into the printer's wireless configuration panel and saw that DHCP wasn't enabled and that the printer was assigned a static IP address of **192.168.1.2**. I simply checked the box to enable DHCP and et voilà!

Thank you all for contributing and leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What are the IP addresses of your router, printer, netbook?  What are the gateways set to?  Sounds almost as if you're getting some sort of IP address conflict.  Basically, if the printer is set to an address and your computer gets the same address, everything will initially be okay since the printer may not be sending out much in the way of packets, but once you start sending jobs to the printer the traffic from the printer becomes two way and now you have two active devices with the same address.  Check the gateway addresses as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the printer and the netbook drop from the WiFi when the printer traffic is going I'd suspect the router as the trouble spot.

Perhaps go to the manufacturer of the router, get the latest firmware and update the router.

Other things to try/test (if available) that may lead to the culprit:

- Try setting up an Ad-Hoc wireless network between just the netbook and the printer (removing the router from the equation).
- Try wires.
- Try a different router.