# Vista laptop loses wireless connection when printing

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-router, printer

I have a frustrating problem involving a brand new Canon MX885 printer and a Sony Vaio laptop running Vista Home Premium.

Both the laptop and the printer are connected to the same wireless network.

When I print a document (e.g. a Word document) the printer starts printing correctly. After printing a strip across the top of the page it will then stop, pause and eject the paper.

The laptop will wait for around a minute and then report an error. However it appears that when this happens it has lost it's connection to the wireless network.

At this point the printer is still connected to the wireless network, and I can print from a different computer (a MacBook Pro).

The wireless router everything is connected to hands out IP's using DHCP, in the range 192.168.1.64 - 192.168.1.237.

The problem sounds similar to that reported in [Printing to wireless printer disconnects netbook from router](https://superuser.com/questions/105681/printing-to-wireless-printer-disconnects-netbook-from-router), with the exception that in my case the printer doesn't lose it's wireless connection.